# PhoneGap inside Android application using tabs/fragments

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, tabs, android-fragments

I'm trying to create and application with tabs and fragments with one of the fragments containing Phonegap/javascript code.

I had some code that works when just in a phonegap application (no fragments) but when I put the code into a fragment it stops working...

For example, this code below isn't even working...:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>


    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady(){
        alert("woot i loaded");
    }


</script>
</head>
</html>
```

My initial though is that the code is being run before I go to the tab. The tab with the phonegap code is not the default tab, so maybe it loads when the app loads and thats why I don't see anything?

```
public class DevicesListFragment extends Fragment{

    CordovaWebView webView; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = new CordovaWebView(getActivity());
        **webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");**
            //maybe this is loading and running js before I switch to that tab?
    }
}
```

Do I need to do anything special when working with PhoneGap inside an Android application with tabs and fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all try to implement the app in mobile/emulator not in the browser

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Device Ready Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use device APIs
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="onLoad()">
      </body>
    </html>
```

MyPhoneGapActivity.java

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

or else refer the line which is provided below

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events

Comment: Ah okay so I was correct in saying that js was running before i switched tabs! thanks!